# Multiple Useful-Buttons on same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've made a "Useful-Button" with jQuery so user can rate e.g. an answer of a question (like the upvote function here on stackoverflow).

```js
function submitForm() {
 var form = document.myform;
 var dataString = $(form).serialize();
 
 $.ajax({
  type:'POST',
    url:'like_submit.php',
    data: dataString,
    success: function(data){
     $('#myResponse').html(data);
     $('#myResponse').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
    }
   });
   return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform" class="myform" method="post" name="myform">
 Was this 1. answer helpful?
  <input type="hidden" name="answer_id" value="1" />
  <input  class="label__checkbox" type="checkbox" name="helpful" onclick="submitForm()" />
</form>
<div id="myResponse"></div>
```

The like_submit.php is like this:

```
<?php
$helpful = $_POST['helpful'];
$answer_id = $_POST['answer_id'];
echo "Thank you! Helpful? $helpful | AnswerID: $answer_id";
?>
```

So for one answer it works.

But now I want to add more than one answer and I doesn't know how get the script to work for this case.

If I add a second form...

```
<form id="myform" class="myform" method="post" name="myform">
Was this 2. answer helpful?
  <input type="hidden" name="answer_id" value="2" />
  <input  class="label__checkbox" type="checkbox" name="helpful" onclick="submitForm()" />
</form>
<div id="myResponse"></div>
```

... I have two problems. I only get the last POST-data right. If I click the first form, it says:
Thank you! Helpful? on | AnswerID: 2

Second problem, the response message appears allways an the first position.

Can anyone help? Many thanks!

Comment: I'd like to warn you about using IDs... your #myForm and #myResponse will be shown more than once in your page, if I get what you want to do. This is just a big NO-NO. You'll want to use classes, IDs should be unique.

Comment: Yes, thank you, good hint @Salketer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the elements relative to the submitted form

html:
`onclick="submitForm(this)"`

js:

```
function submitForm(el) {
    var form = $(el).closest('form');
    var dataString = form.serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
    url:'like_submit.php',
    data: dataString,
    success: function(data){
        form.next('#myResponse').html(data);
        form.next('#myResponse').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
    }
   });
   return false;
}
```

```js
function submitForm(el) {
 var form = $(el).closest('form');
 var dataString = form.serialize();
     form.next('#myResponse').html(dataString);
     form.next('#myResponse').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform" class="myform" method="post" name="myform">
 Was this 1. answer helpful?
  <input type="hidden" name="answer_id" value="1" />
  <input  class="label__checkbox" type="checkbox" name="helpful" onclick="submitForm(this)" />
</form>
<div id="myResponse"></div>
<form id="myform" class="myform" method="post" name="myform">
Was this 2. answer helpful?
  <input type="hidden" name="answer_id" value="2" />
  <input  class="label__checkbox" type="checkbox" name="helpful" onclick="submitForm(this)" />
</form>
<div id="myResponse"></div>
```

Comment: This would still submit the form with answer_id=1

Comment: @Salketer this will submit any form that calls submitForm() from a input in its body

Comment: sorry, read too fast. I'd remove the ID from the form, to make sure there is no duplicated ID if this form is to be shown multiple times on a page.

Comment: I think it works great now! Thank you @madalinivascu